# Build Action on VisualStudio Web Site project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, publish, publishing

I need to add arbitrary file types to a VisualStudio **Web Site** project and have them publish with the site.

Converting the project to a Web Application is simply not an option as it is huge.

I need my publish to include (copy) random files such as licenses (.lic) and other files in the future.

My current problem is a .lic library license in the Bin folder. I need this to be copied over when publishing. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: I have thought of putting it as an embedded resource or putting it in the Scripts or Images folder which are both less than ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a bin folder to your web site project, add the license file to it and then use Website -> Copy Website option from the menu and copy the license file. In here you can have full control over what files you deploy to where.